# Manage phone calls with node.js using Android

Tags: android, node.js, npm, adb, voice

I'm making a node.js app that control calls in android phone, I'm using the npm mudule ADB and was able to make calls as bellow:

```
adb -s <serialno> shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:123-456
```

Unfortunately I was not able to manage the audio and control it from my app.

My question is: 
Is there a way to send and receive the voice between my application and the phone (Without using any third party like twilio)?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is there any way to make a phone call via npm Adb??